# ajax returns each letter when return JSON value issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

am not sure this may be duplicate... Please help me on this issue

Am trying to get 3 Mysql values to jquery ajax function. but i can't able to display the values. i have used many of the methods described in various posts. but nothing was matched for me.

Below is my php page

```
$equipm = array();
$service = array();
$facility = array();
$result = array();
$equip_sel   = "select * from equipment";
$run_equip   = mysqli_query($con,$equip_sel);

while($rowe =mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_equip))
{
    $equipm[] = $rowe;
}
$serv_sel    = "select * from services";
$run_serv    = mysqli_query($con,$serv_sel);
while($rows =mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_serv))
{
    $servc[] = $rows;
}

$faci_sel    = "select * from specility ";
$run_fac     = mysqli_query($con,$faci_sel);
while($rowf =mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_fac))
{
    $facility[] = $rowf;
}

//$result[0]=$equipm;
//$result[1]=$servc;
//$result[2]=$facility;
$result=array('equipment'=>array($equipm), 'services'=> array($servc),     'facility'=> array($facility));
echo json_encode($result);
```

and below is my jquery,

```
   <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            /* call the php that has the php array which is json_encoded enter code here*/
            $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "ajax2.php",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function(data) {
            alert(data[0]);
            });

            }
        });

    });
    </script>
```

above results every single character from the output table.

please help on here. each time it returns one character.

Comment: What does it do: Display everything or just display one character (poorly posed question)...

Comment: I can't check the code now, I think here is something wrong. Your '$equipm' already is an array and your result looks like 'array('equipment'=>array(array(...));'. Is that right for your expectations? Your jQuery alerts 'data[0]', but I suggest json will have 'data.equipment'.

Answer (score 0):

There are syntax errors in your jquery because of closing brackets and parentheses. Here is the fixed version which worked for me.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        /* call the php that has the php array which is json_encoded enter code here*/
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "ajax2.php",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data[0]);
            }
        });        
    });

</script>
```